# How to get partition where value belongs in partitioned interval?

Tags: c++, std

I have interval that is partitioned int large amount of smaller partitions.

There aren't any spaces also there aren't any overlapping intervals.

E.g: `(0;600)` is separated into:

1. `(0;10>`
2. `(10;25>`
3. `(25;100>`
4. `(100;125>`
5. `(125;550>`
6. `(550;600)`

Now i have large amount of values and i need to get partition id for each of them.
I can store array of values that partitions this interval into smaller intervals.
But if all values belongs to last partition it'll need to pass through whole array.

So i'm searching for any better solution to store these intervals. I want simple - max cca 150 lines length algorithm and i don't want to use any library except std.

Comment: So, basically, you want us to write it for you?

Comment: I don't want you to write it for me. But give me some point or algorithm that helps me with it.

Comment: I don't find this very clear: When you say (0,10), (10,25), where does the 10 belong? Also, "partition" already means an exhaustive, non-overlapping covering, so that every member of the range is in a unique set of the partition. So your second sentence is superfluous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there are no "empty spaces" in your partitioning, the end of each partition is redundant (it's the same as the start of the next partition).

And since you have the partition list sorted, you can simply use binary search, with [`std::upper_bound`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/upper_bound/).

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/1xtZG)**.

**Edit:** Correction (`upper_bound`, not `lower_bound`).

Comment: @Miro: `std::map` of what? But in general yes you can; there is a [`std::map::upper_bound`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/upper_bound/) method as well.

Comment: Because of i need to get the id of interval where value belongs.

Answer (score 1):

You could just improve your search algorithm.

Put all the ranges in the array, and then use **[Binary Search Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)** to search for the right range.

It will cost O(logn), and it's really easy to implement.

Comment: I have to say that in my experience, binary search is notoriously hard to implement correctly for something that *sounds* so simple. :)